# jruby no such file to load application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I have a project in jRuby that I try to run. 
So I'm installling jruby using rvm like this

`rvm install jruby-9.1.15.0` (bc thats the version required by the project)

then im making sure that im actually using jruby by typing
`ruby -v` which shows me that I have jruby

next thing, I want to run the rails server so I'm typing

`bundle exec rails server`

and unfortunately I get an error:

```
/Users/foouser/Documents/Projects/fooproject/bin/config/application
LoadError: no such file to load -- /Users/foouser/Documents/Projects/fooproject/bin/config/application
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
  block in server at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78
              tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1741
           server at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75
     run_command! at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
           <main> at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
           <main> at bin/rails:5
```

I've tried googling that but to no avail. People seem to not encounter this issue at all. I'm sure it's got something to do with my setup because other people are successfully using said project.

Any ideas?

rails version - 4.2
jruby version - 9.1.15.0

EDIT:

after some digging, in `bin/rails` file the line defining the `APP_PATH` was like that:

`APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application',  __FILE__)`

which somehow made it looking for application.rb inside `fooproject/bin/config` instead of `fooproject/config`

but when I changed the line to

`APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)`

it goes to the correct path where application.rb exist but still reports it as not existing.

the error is nearly the same (apart for path)

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- /Users/foouser/Documents/Projects/fooproject/config/application
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
  block in server at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78
              tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1741
           server at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75
     run_command! at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
           <main> at /Users/foouser/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.15.0-jrubu/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:955
           <main> at bin/rails:4
```

EDIT 2:

requested permissions for application.rb:

`-rw-r--r--  1 foouser  staff  5818 20 Jun 15:12 config/application.rb`

config.ru:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: and what about application.rb file ?

Comment: could you clarify the question please, what about it?

Comment: Permission of application.rb + content of project/config.ru 
 and project/config/environment.rb

Comment: @D1ceWard I've updated my question with the info you've requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I have is the "have you tried to turn it off and on again?" type.
I have deleted the whole project and cloned it again from the repo.
Everything is working now, it must have been something with my local env but I can't tell what.

Anyway, if you ever encounter something similar - purge and clone is definitely something you can try.